# Return one item from filtered Array

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, air

I want to return just 1 item in the filtered array
my code is

```
private function audioProgress(event:Event):void{
        var wordindex:int=0;
        function filterFun(element:int, index:int, array:Array):Boolean {
            return (element < soundChannel.position);
        }
        var arr:Array=soundPositions.filter(filterFun);
}
```

I want "arr" to contains just one item 
How can I do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read your code correctly, you are trying to sync to a playing sound? Then using Array.filter is inefficient - you only need to keep track of the most recently passed marker.

Assuming that your soundPositions array is numerically sorted, this can be done in a simple loop:

```
private var current : int = 0;

private function audioProgress(event:Event):void{
    while( current < soundPositions.length -1 && 
           soundPositions[current+1] < soundChannel.position ) 
                current++; 
    doStuffWith(soundPositions[current]);
}
```

This way, there will only be one iteration of the array - total.  The while loop starts at the current index, and it will exit when the value is greater than or equal to the sound's position, so `current` will always point to the last item the (virtual) playhead has passed.

Answer (score 1):

You need the index of the item you want. If you just want the first item, use:

```
arr[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Another variant to get one item from the initial array:

```
private function audioProgress(event:Event):void{
        var wordindex:int=0;
        var firstRequiredItemIndex:int = -1;
        function filterFun(element:int, index:int, array:Array):Boolean {
            if (element < soundChannel.position)
            {
                 firstRequiredItemIndex = index;
                 return true;
            }
            else
            {
                 return false;
            }
        }

        if (soundPositions.some(filterFun))
        {
            // Your element
            soundPositions[firstRequiredItemIndex];
        }
}
```

The function 'some' executes a test function on each item in the array until an item is reached that returns true. So there is no need to check the whole array.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#some%28%29

Comment: The function will always loop through the array from the beginning, though, and since the sound's position increases over time, the iterations will become longer and longer.